# How to Ensure a REST API Is Accessed Only by Known Consumers

Tags: api, rest, http, api-key, secret-key

To ensure a REST API is accessed only by known consumers, client applications use to sign each HTTP request with a **secret** and then send the resulting **signature** togheter with the **API key** to the server.

In case of JavaScript clients the **API key** and **secret** are hardcoded in the script itself... so how does this mechanism ensure a client sending the request is really the client it is supposed to be? I'm asking because if the **secret** is hardcoded in the JavaScript, everybody could look at it, steal the **secret**, and use it in other applications.

Is there a safer way to expose an API to consumers? I know there are other posts in Stackoverflow covering this topic... but what is not clear to me is how to deal with both consumer authorization and user authorization. In my case, consumer authorization determintes whether or not a third party is allowd to access my API and has nothing to do with business logic, while user authorization is at application level (i.e. after the consumer has been identified and authorized).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After some googling I found this [great article](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2013/09/12/securing-api-keys-in-a-client-side-javascript-app/) and just implemented the solution it describes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can check the domain and provide a SOP setting to restrict to only known domains.
You can drop requests by origin ip if the ips are going to be constant.

Moreover you can have a secret generator on your server which client need to call from there on servers and pass it on their js code, from there it can be attached to api call. This way client with SOP can make sure that their js is not injected. You can check on the clients IP before providing the response.

Basically, it would depend on the type of consumers you going to serve. Are they enterprise customers, etc.